# LCD (I2C) issues with pull up resistor

Tags: i2c, temperature-sensor, u8glib

I'm close to finish my first DYI project. But a never seen issue on the breadboard has apprear as soon as assembled.

The LCD is always / totally blank/black.

When I remove the 4.7 K ohm pull-up resistor from my 2 temperature sensors 18b20 the LCD works like a charm but temperature sensor doens't work. If a reconnect the pull-up resistor when the LCD is OK the temperature is displayed.

So it could be a wrong initialisation in my code (maybe during last cleaning)
Or a bad way to do this with my sensors and resistors.

I have theory but I'm quite a noob on electronic. What do you think I can do to resolve that ?

Thanks,

.
.
.

It's a LoLin card an not a Wemos.

[image: Scheme]

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <TimeLib.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

#define PIN_DZero D4    // LCD PIN D0
#define PIN_DOne D3     // LCD PIN D1
#define PIN_RESET D2    // LCD PIN RST
#define PIN_DC D1       // LCD PIN DC

#define PIN_TEMP D8     // TEMP PIN
#define PIN_BtnMoins D6 // Button -
#define PIN_BtnPlus D7  // Button +
#define PIN_RELAY D0    // RELAY PIN
#define PIN_UV A0       // UV ANALOG PIN

// Temperature sensor
#include <Wire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
OneWire oneWire(PIN_TEMP); // Setup a oneWire instance to communicate with any OneWire devices  
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire); // Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature. 

// LCD
#include <U8g2lib.h>
#include <U8x8lib.h>
U8G2_SSD1306_128X64_NONAME_F_4W_SW_SPI u8g2(U8G2_R0, PIN_DZero, PIN_DOne, U8X8_PIN_NONE, PIN_DC, PIN_RESET);


ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;

/*-----SENSOR VALUES-----*/
float sensorUVvolt ;
float sensorUV ;
float sensorTemp0 ;
float sensorTemp1 ;
String macAddress = "";
String txtWebService = "";
String txtTime ;
String txtSunRise;
String txtSunSet ;
int utcTime ;
int utcSunRise;
int utcSunSet ;
long timeLast = -55000;
bool isInternetConnected = 0;
bool isLampOn = 0;

time_t timeNow = now();
int minuteSunRise = 0;
int minuteSunSet = 0;

bool previousBlink = 0;
int menu = 0;
bool freezeMenu = 0;
unsigned int paramMinuteTimeNow; 
unsigned int paramMinuteSunRise;
unsigned int paramMinuteSunSet; 
int paramLampMode = 0; // AUTO

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  digitalWrite(PIN_RELAY, LOW); 
  pinMode(PIN_RELAY, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(PIN_RELAY, LOW); 

  pinMode(PIN_BtnMoins, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(PIN_BtnPlus, INPUT_PULLUP);
  //pinMode(PIN_TEMP, INPUT_PULLUP);

  txtTime = "1990-01-01 00:00:00";
  setTime(txtTime.substring(11, 13).toInt(), txtTime.substring(14, 16).toInt(), txtTime.substring(17, 19).toInt(), txtTime.substring(8, 10).toInt(), txtTime.substring(5, 7).toInt(), txtTime.substring(0, 4).toInt()); // Another way to set

  Serial.setDebugOutput(true);

  Serial.println(".");
  Serial.println(".");
  Serial.println(".");

  sensors.begin();

  u8g2.begin();


  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFiMulti.addAP("WIFINAME", "PASS"); 
  macAddress = WiFi.macAddress();

}

void GetAllSensorValues() {

  sensorUVvolt = 3.3 * analogRead(PIN_UV) / 1024; ;  //*100/1024;
    sensorUV = mapfloat(sensorUVvolt, 1.06, 2.9, 0.0, 15.0);
    if (sensorUV <= 0 ) sensorUV =0;

  sensors.requestTemperatures(); // Send the command to get temperature readings 
    sensorTemp0 = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
    sensorTemp1 = sensors.getTempCByIndex(1);

    if (sensorTemp0 <= 0 ) sensorTemp0 =0;
    if (sensorTemp1 <= 0 ) sensorTemp1 =0;

}


void ActuorAll() {
  if (paramLampMode == 3) {
    digitalWrite(PIN_RELAY, HIGH);
  } else if (paramLampMode == 2) {
    digitalWrite(PIN_RELAY, LOW);
  } else {
    if ( minuteSunSet != minuteSunRise && minuteSunSet != 0 && minuteSunSet > minuteSunRise && year(timeNow) != 1982 && hour(timeNow) + minute(timeNow) !=0 ) {
      if (  minuteSunRise + paramMinuteSunRise <= 60 * hour(timeNow) + minute(timeNow) + paramMinuteTimeNow && 60 * hour(timeNow) + minute(timeNow) + paramMinuteTimeNow <= minuteSunSet + paramMinuteSunSet  ) {
        isLampOn = 1;
        digitalWrite(PIN_RELAY, HIGH);
      } else {
        isLampOn = 0;
        digitalWrite(PIN_RELAY, LOW);
      }
    }
  }
}


//The Arduino Map function but for floats
float mapfloat(float x, float in_min, float in_max, float out_min, float out_max)
{
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}

void loop() {

  boolean btnPlus = !digitalRead(PIN_BtnPlus);
  boolean btnMoins = !digitalRead(PIN_BtnMoins);

  if ( !freezeMenu && btnMoins==HIGH && btnPlus==HIGH ) {
      if (menu >= 6) {
        menu = 0;
        freezeMenu = 1;
      } else {
        menu++;
        freezeMenu = 1;
      }
  }

  if ( btnMoins==LOW || btnPlus==LOW) {
    freezeMenu = 0;
  }

  if (menu != 0) {
    if (previousBlink) {     
      previousBlink = 0;
    } else {
      previousBlink = 1;
    }
    if (menu == 2 && btnMoins==HIGH) { paramMinuteTimeNow=paramMinuteTimeNow-10; }
    if (menu == 2 && btnPlus==HIGH) { paramMinuteTimeNow=paramMinuteTimeNow+10; }
    if (menu == 3 && btnMoins==HIGH) { paramLampMode--; }
    if (menu == 3 && btnPlus==HIGH) { paramLampMode++; }
    if (menu == 5 && btnMoins==HIGH) { paramMinuteSunRise=paramMinuteSunRise-10; }
    if (menu == 5 && btnPlus==HIGH) { paramMinuteSunRise=paramMinuteSunRise+10; }
    if (menu == 6 && btnMoins==HIGH) { paramMinuteSunSet=paramMinuteSunSet-10; }
    if (menu == 6 && btnPlus==HIGH) { paramMinuteSunSet=paramMinuteSunSet+10; }
  } else {
    previousBlink = 0;
  }

  if (paramLampMode>3) {paramLampMode=0;}
  if (paramLampMode<0) {paramLampMode=3;}

  GetAllSensorValues();

  if ( millis()-timeLast >= 60000 ) { 

    WebServiceCall("UV", String(sensorUV), "Temp0", String(sensorTemp0), "Temp1", String(sensorTemp1) );

    timeLast = millis();
  }

  ActuorAll();

  DisplayLCD();

  delay(500);
}




void DisplayLCD(){
  String line1 = "";
  String line2 = "";
  String line3 = "";

  float txtTemp0 = round(sensorTemp0*10);
  txtTemp0 = txtTemp0/10;
  float txtTemp1 = round(sensorTemp1*10);    
  txtTemp1 = txtTemp1 /10;

  /*Serial.print(" | minute timeNow:");
  Serial.print(minute(timeNow));
  Serial.print(" | A0:");
  Serial.print(sensorUVvolt);
  Serial.print("V ");
  Serial.print(sensorUV);
  Serial.print(" mW/cm² | temp0:");
  Serial.print(sensorTemp0);
  Serial.print("°C | temp1 ");
  Serial.print(sensorTemp1);
  Serial.println("°C");
  */
  u8g2.clearBuffer();
  u8g2.setFont(u8g2_font_helvB12_tf);

  /* ------- LINE 1 ------- */
  if (menu == 1 && previousBlink) line1 = macAddress;  
  if (menu != 1) line1 = String(txtTemp0).substring(0, 4) + " | " + String(txtTemp1).substring(0, 4) + " | " + String(sensorUV);

  /* ------- LINE 2 ------- */

  String dsplTime = MinuteToTime(60*hour(timeNow)+minute(timeNow)+paramMinuteTimeNow);
  if (menu == 2 && previousBlink) dsplTime = "__:__";  

  String txtLamp = GetLampMode();
  if (menu == 3 && previousBlink) txtLamp = "____";  

  String txtInternet = "X";
  if (isInternetConnected) txtInternet = "@";
  if (menu == 4 && previousBlink) txtInternet  = "_";  

    line2 = dsplTime+ "  " +txtLamp+ "  " +txtInternet;  

  /* ------- LINE 3 ------- */
  String dsplSunRise = MinuteToTime(minuteSunRise+paramMinuteSunRise);
  if (menu == 5 && previousBlink) dsplSunRise  = "__:__";  

  String dsplSunSet = MinuteToTime(minuteSunSet+paramMinuteSunSet);
  if (menu == 6 && previousBlink) dsplSunSet  = "__:__";  

    line3 = "  " +dsplSunRise+ " > " +dsplSunSet; 

  u8g2.drawStr(0,12, line1.c_str() );
  u8g2.drawStr(0,35, line2.c_str() );
  u8g2.drawStr(0,55, line3.c_str() );

  u8g2.sendBuffer();

}
String GetLampMode(){
  if (paramLampMode == 3) {return "ON";}
  else if (paramLampMode == 2) {return "OFF";}
  else {return "AUTO";}

}

String MinuteToTime(int min) {
  int resutHour = min/60;
  int resutMin = min - resutHour*60;
  String resultTime = String(resutHour);

  if (resutHour < 10) {
    resultTime = "0" + String(resutHour);
  }
  if (resutMin < 10 ) {
    resultTime = resultTime + ":0" + String(resutMin);
  } else {
    resultTime = resultTime + ":" + String(resutMin);
  }

  return resultTime;

}

int WebServiceCall(String sensor1Id , String sensor1Value, String sensor2Id , String sensor2Value, String sensor3Id , String sensor3Value) {
  String url = "http://MYWEBSERVICE/save?mac=" + macAddress + "&sensor1id=" + sensor1Id + "&sensor1value=" + sensor1Value + "&sensor1id=" + sensor2Id + "&sensor2value=" + sensor2Value + "&sensor3id=" + sensor3Id + "&sensor3value=" + sensor3Value;
  Serial.println("[HTTP] url is:" + url);
  // wait for WiFi connection
  if ((WiFiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED)) {
    isInternetConnected = 1;
    WiFiClient client;

    HTTPClient http;

    Serial.print("[HTTP] begin...\n");
    if (http.begin(client, url)) {  // HTTP

      Serial.print("[HTTP] GET...\n");
      // start connection and send HTTP header
      int httpCode = http.GET();

      // httpCode will be negative on error
      if (httpCode > 0) {
        // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
        Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);

        // file found at server
        if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK || httpCode == HTTP_CODE_MOVED_PERMANENTLY) {
          String payload = http.getString();
          Serial.print("JSON:" + payload);
          txtWebService= payload;     
          StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;
          DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, payload);

          if (error) {
            Serial.print("[HTTP] JSON error ");
            Serial.println(error.c_str());
            //return;
          }

          JsonObject root = doc.as<JsonObject>();
          txtTime = root["time"].as<String>();
          txtSunRise = root["sunRise"].as<String>();
          txtSunSet = root["sunSet"].as<String>();
          minuteSunRise = 60 * txtSunRise.substring(11, 13).toInt() + txtSunRise.substring(14, 16).toInt();
          minuteSunSet = 60 * txtSunSet.substring(11, 13).toInt() + txtSunSet.substring(14, 16).toInt();

          setTime(txtTime.substring(11, 13).toInt(), txtTime.substring(14, 16).toInt(), txtTime.substring(17, 19).toInt(), txtTime.substring(8, 10).toInt(), txtTime.substring(5, 7).toInt(), txtTime.substring(0, 4).toInt()); // Another way to set
          //Serial.printf("[TIME] TimeNow %s\n", txtTime);
          //Serial.printf("[TIME] hour %d\n", txtTime.substring(11, 13).toInt());
          //Serial.printf("[TIME] minute %d\n", txtTime.substring(14, 16).toInt());

        }
      } else {
        Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
      }

      http.end();
    } else {
      Serial.printf("[HTTP} Unable to connect\n");
      //isInternetConnected = 0;
    }
  } else {
    isInternetConnected = 0;
  }


}
```

Comment: tip: `previousBlink` is boolean, so use `true/false` for the values ............................. also, you can reduce `if (previousBlink) { previousBlink = 0; } else { previousBlink = 1; }` to just `previousBlink = !previousBlink;`

Comment: what happens if you remove one of the sensors?

Comment: Thanks @jsotola. With only the relay & 1 sensor it do the same. Blank if connected at launching - LCD OK if the pull-up resistor is not connected at launching

Comment: Youtube video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwbx0FxLWJ4

Comment: start at the beginning ..... leave everything connected ..... run LCD demo sketch

Comment: Thnaks @jsotola for your support I found the error.

Comment: ... by doing it again and with observation on a few GPIO maps (lolin 32 pro, Wemos mini, ...). The GPIO pins cannot be used as you want and you have dedicated I2C and SPI pins. My conclusion is (not sure of that): the temperature sensors cannot use the SPI pins when you have an I2C. I switched sensor pin on my test breadboard from D8 to D4 (youtube link) and it's OK. I will not do a deep study on my project already soldered but will try a few other pins and I hope it will work ![Valid XHTML](https://escapequotes.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/esp8266-wemos-d1-mini-pinout.png).